# Is it possible to score correct/incorrect answers in Qualtrics without a JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have to build a survey where the participants have to solve addition problems, and score their results in dependencs of the correctness of their answers. Unfortunnately, I am new to JavaScript and would struggle with writing a program for this. Are there possibilities to do this in Qualtrics without using JavaScript? (And if not, how would be an approach for tackling this problem using JavaScript?)

Comment: Are you trying to design a survey or a quiz? If it is a quiz, is it to be scored?

If not a survey, there are many examples of quiz programs in JS.

Keep in mind that if used for a "grade", JS is a poor way to secure the answers.

Comment: No, it is a survey (or rather an experiment) where a treatment and its effect on the participants' results is tested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Qualtrics Scoring](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/scoring/) feature.

Comment: Thank you! I think I figuered it out now.